# How to solve the, calling for Mono<Token> then the result will be used to another Mono<Collection>, which will then return Mono<collection>?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-mono

Hi I just started learning reactive programming

I have this piece of code here and my process here should be
I will call tokenRepository to get the token and then, use the token.getAccessToken() to be used as a parameter on the cardRepository.findAllCards()

```java
public class CardService {

    private final CardRepository cardRepository;
    private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;

    public CardService(CardRepositorycardRepository,
                       TokenRepository tokenRepository) {
        this.cardRepository = cardRepository;
        this.tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
    }

    public Mono<CardCollection> findAllCards(MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams) {
        Mono<Token> token =tokenRepository.requestToken(); 

        // then I would like to use the token.getAccessToken
        return cardRepository.findAllCards(token.getAccessToken, queryParams); // Then this should return Mono<CardCollection>
    }
}
```

Would like to know if this is possible?

Comment: Why do you think it is not? You have to give more information this piece of code.

Comment: @papaya because you need to subscribe before you could extract the data

Comment: what does `cardRepository.findAllCards` return?

Comment: @Shoshi it returns Mono<CardCollection>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer although I'm not quite sure if this is the correct way.

[How to pass data down the reactive chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340599/how-to-pass-data-down-the-reactive-chain)

This is what I've done with my code.

```java
public Mono<CardCollection> findAllCards(MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams) {
  return tokenRepository.requestToken().flatMap(token -> {
      return cardRepository.findAllCards(token.getAccessToken(), queryParams);
  });
}
```

Comment: that is correct as long as the token repository is using a non blocking database driver, or restclient (like webflux) to fetch the token.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndolf, are there any elegant way to do this? what if there's a large flow for this specific method?

Comment: that looks rather elegant already, what about if there is a large flow, do you see any problem with that?

Comment: Be aware about what if tokenRepository.requestToken() return null or empty token

Comment: @ThomasAndolf nothing really, I just thought there is another way to do things. Thanks for validating my answers it was truly helpful.

Comment: @Shoshi yes, currently looking on how to that properly thanks for the heads up :D

Comment: For that you should use switchifempty or defaultifempty